# async function javascript is not running in background?

Tags: javascript, async-await

```
console.log("1");
  console.log("2"); 
async function a() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {}
    for (let i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {}
  }
  a().then(() => console.log("in then"));

  console.log("3!");
```

This output I want is this
1
2
3!
in then

but the async function behaves synchronously and does not let the 3! print until after the long loops are done executing. I thought if the async keyword is used, it runs the function inside in the background?
I basically want the 2 long loops to run in the background. Just trying to understand async and await.
Thanks.

Edit:
could someone tell me why this also works synchronously??

````
  console.log("2");

  function lag(resolve) {
    for (let i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {}
    for (let i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {}
    console.log("in lag");
    return resolve;
  }
  async function a() {
    // console.log("its done");
    let a = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => lag(resolve));
  }
  a().then(() => console.log("in then"));

  console.log("3!"); ```
````

Comment: `for` is totally synchronous. You are executing a very CPU-intensive operation, there's nothing asynchronous in it. Remove the `async` keyword, it's totally useless.

Comment: "*thought if the async keyword is used, it runs the function inside in the background?*" no, that's not true and has never worked like that. `async` does not spawn a new process. It *only* allows you to use `await` in the body and then returns a promise. It does automatically handle promise sequencing but it's still all a single thread.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is nothing about `async` functions (or promises) that makes anything run in the background. They don't create a new thread or anything like that.

An `async` function is synchronous until the first `await` or `return`. Since your function doesn't have any `await` or `return`, it's fully synchronous.

The purpose of promises is to observe the completion of something that's *already* asynchronous, such as the browser's loading things via HTTP, or a timer. The purpose of `async` functions is to have syntax for using promises that lets us write the logical flow of the code rather than writing callback functions. Neither of them makes anything asynchronous, or moves things to a different thread.

If you want to run something in the background, you can create a worker thread and exchange information between it and the main thread via messaging. On browsers it's [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker). In Node.js it's the [worker threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html) module.

In your question and in comments on the answer you've talked about how an `async` function seems to wait for an asynchronous task to complete. And indeed, the logic of the function does. But that's really syntactic sugar for using promises (*really, really good syntactic sugar*, IMHO). Let's look at an `async` function:

```js
function delay(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, ms);
    });
}

async function example() {
    // The function starts out synchronous, so that it can
    // start whatever inherently-asynchronous thing it does
    // (like calling `fetch`).
    console.log("[example] This is synchronous");

    // When execution reaches the first `await` or `return`,
    // the `async` function returns a promise. The synchronous
    // part of its work is now complete.
    await delay(10);

    // This code runs later, when/if the promise from `delay`
    // is settled.
    console.log("[example] This is asynchronous, but still on the main thread");

    // If you `throw` in an `async` function, it rejects the `async`
    // function's promise.
    if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
        throw new Error("Error thrown by `example`");
    }

    // The "return" value of an `async` function is the fulfillment
    // value of the promise the `async` function returned
    return 42;
}

console.log("[top] Calling `example`...");
const promiseFromExample = example();
console.log("[top] Back from calling `example`. Waiting for its promise to settle.");
promiseFromExample
.then((value) => {
    console.log(`[top] The promise from \`example\` was fulfilled with the value ${value}`);
})
.catch((reason) => {
    console.log(`[top] The promise from \`example\` was rejected with the rejection reason ${reason.message}`);
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Run that a few times so you see both a fulfillment and a rejection (each run has a 50/50 chance). Nothing in that code runs anywhere but the main thread, it's just that with `await`, the logic in `example` can wait for a promise to settle. The promise from `delay` lets us observe the completion of the timer, then `example` `await`s that completion before continuing its logic.

The key things are:

- Promises don't make anything asynchronous¹
- Promises and `async` functions don't move anything off the main thread
- `async` functions always return promises
- The code in an `async` function runs synchronously until the first `await` or `return`
- The promise from an `async` function gets fulfilled with the return value of the function, or rejected with any error that occurs in the function

---

¹ Okay, there's one caveat to that: If you use `.then` or `.catch` (or `.finally`) to hook up a callback to a promise, that callback will always be called asynchronously, even if the promise is *already* settled.

Comment: FWIW, I go into promises in detail in Chapter 8 and `async` functions in detail in Chapter 9 of my recent book *JavaScript: The New Toys*. Links in my profile if you're interested.

Comment: Hi thanks and I'm interested in checking that chapter. So if I want a set of instructions that  may take more than a few cpu ticks to execute run asynchronously how should I implement it in js? by using await? In the code I posted above, how can I make the "3!" print in the console immediately after "2"? I understood the web workers but I've noticed fetch operations holding up execution of instructions written under them working asynchronously to avoid making the instructions under it wait. is something like that possible for instructions I can write?

Comment: @TheSlyOne - The only way to have CPU-intensive code not block the main thread is to put it on another thread -- a worker thread. Neither promises nor `async` functions do that for you. The reason `fetch` is asynchronous is that the browser handles doing the HTTP request by just having `fetch` *start* the process, returning a promise, and later fulfilling or rejecting that promise when it has the result. An `async` function using `fetch` is basically only asynchronous because `fetch` is. I've expanded the answer to try to illustrate that a bit. Happy coding!