# Asynchronous Javascript Confusion

Tags: javascript, function, asynchronous

I am fairly new to Javascript and am writing this post off the top of my head, so please correct me if I am wrong with anything.

From what I know, asynchronous functions allow other processes to run in the background and then after the function is completed, it returns a promise that can either be resolved or rejected. Also since processes in async functions don’t run in a set order, we can use the await keyword to stop execution until a process is completed.

However, what baffles me is the difference in code execution between

```
function f1() {
  //do stuff
}

function f2() {
  //do stuff
}

function f3() {
  //do stuff
}

async function asyncFunc() {
  f1()
  f2()
  f3()
}

asyncFunc()
```

and this:

```
async function asyncf1() {
  //do stuff
}

async function asyncf2() {
  //do stuff
}

async function asyncf3() {
  //do stuff
}

function f() {
  asyncf1()
  asyncf2()
  asyncf3()
}

f()
```

?????
(Apart from the obvious fact that the first example returns a promise)

Is calling async functions in a sync function the same thing as calling sync functions in an async function? Do they both result in the same output? If so, which one is preferred over the other?

Comment: well there are no awaits in your code... so it will be the same. What is preferred depends on the task at hand.

Comment: *asynchronous functions allow other processes to run in the background and then after the function is completed, it returns a promise that can either be resolved or rejected.* <-- Just because an operation is asynchronous doesn't mean that you'll have promises that can be resolved or rejected - - that's specifically available with the Promise API. AJAX operations are asynchronous but don't give you resolve/reject abilities natively.

Comment: Research suggestion - 1. what async functions actually do. 2. Multithreading in JavaScript. Specifically how it's an opt-in and most of the code still runs single-threaded.

Comment: The first one works, the second one doesn't. Whether to use async features is usually not your decision. Async functions *have* to be called from async functions (or async-aware sites that handle the resulting promises properly)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67354276/async-function-javascript-is-not-running-in-background

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key thing to understand is that `async` functions are syntactic sugar for using *promises*. Neither `async` functions nor promises make anything happen in the background. They let you wait for and react to things that *already* happen in the background (like a timer or an HTTP operation completing).

An `async` function is **synchronous** up until the first `await` or `return`. (That's so it can *start* whatever asynchronous process it then waits for.) At that point, it returns a promise that will be fulfilled or rejected depending on what happens to the promise being `await`ed and/or what you return.

`await` pauses the logic of the function until/unless the promise being `await`ed settles. (If you use `await value` where `value` isn't a *thenable* [a promise-like thing], you're effectively doing `await Promise.resolve(value)`.)

You haven't shown any contents of the `asyncFuncX` functions, but unless they `await` something, they're fully synchronous.

You may find [my answer from a couple of days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67354326/157247) useful as well.

Comment: I hadn't realized `async` functions are sync until the first `await`. My mental model had been that they are basically always dispatched into a task. TIL, thank you :)

Comment: @AKX - :-) A pleasure!

Comment: @ Jackbaklava (well, or anyone else) I go into Promises and `async` functions in a fair bit of detail in Chapters 8 and 9 of my recent book *JavaScript: The New Toys*. Links in my profile if you're interested.

Comment: @AKX if you have any familiarity with [C++20 coroutines](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/coroutines), the JavaScript implementation of `async` is the equivalent of using the `suspend_never` type for the `initial_suspend()` suspension point in the state machine, meaning async functions in JavaScript are _eagerly_ started rather than _lazily_ started. Conversely, generator functions in JavaScript are the equivalent of using the `suspend_always` type for the `initial_suspend()` suspension point since they are _lazily_ started and only begin execution after calling `generator.next()`.

Comment: I sometimes wonder what JavaScript would have been like if `async` had been implemented by using a microtask to dispatch from the event loop for the initial suspension point. I suppose this particular implementation was inevitable though because the code generation for pre-ES2017 equivalent `async` would have been a pain to get right if that was the case.

Comment: Oh! So they are the same since I am not using any awaits. That explains everything. Thanks! :) @T.J.Crowder

Answer (score 4):

> Is calling async functions in a sync function the same thing as calling sync functions in an async function?

Not at all. `async` functions are arranged by the JavaScript execution environment to be executed in separate [microtasks](https://javascript.info/microtask-queue) (after the first `await`, [as explained in TJ Crowder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67373126/51685)), out of the flow of the synchronous function. This means that `async` functions (can) continue running after the calling synchronous function has been `return`ed out of.

If you run the below snippet, you can see the output being `in`, `out`, `f1`, `f2`, `f3`, even if the `f` function clearly seems to do `in`, `f1`, `f2`, `f3`, `out`.

(The example has an extra `await noop()` to truly make the async happen.)

```js
async function noop() {}

async function asyncf1() {
  await noop();
  console.log('f1');
}

async function asyncf2() {
  await noop();
  console.log('f2');
}

async function asyncf3() {
  await noop();
  console.log('f3');
}

function f() {
  console.log('in');
  asyncf1();
  asyncf2();
  asyncf3();
  console.log('out');
}

f()
```

Conversely, calling a synchronous function in an `async` function works, but has the effect of blocking that task, and since JavaScript engines are single-threaded wrt JavaScript code, it blocks all other `async` tasks from executing "simultaneously" too.

> Do they both result in the same output?

They don't. (Or, well, that's a philosophical question. If the functions don't return anything or do anything, then yes, the result could be perceived to be the same.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Clarified.

Comment: "*If you run the below snippet, you can see the output being in, out, f1, f2, f3*" only in *this* specific example. If there is no `await` in `asyncf2`, for example, then you'd get in -> f2 -> out -> f1 -> f3